# Kendo MVC Grid Create action "maxJsonLength exceed"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 and I am posting an view model which is of the following format:

```js
{
  row: {
      ...
      DocumentID: ...
      FileName: ...
      FileContent: .... //Very Very long base64 string
      ...
  }
}
```

And here is my Kendo MVC Grid Create Action

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Grid_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, MyViewModel row)
{
  // THE PROGRAM DID NOT EVEN STEP INTO THIS LINE
  try
  {
   ...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("ERROR", ex.Message);
  }
  return Json(...);
}
```

Where `MyViewModel` is a class corresponding to `row` so that by ASP.NET parameter binding mechanism the field value is bound automatically.

Everything was fine, until the file is so large that once the Grid fires Create event, it gives me `Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.`

I have set Maximum JSON length in web.config as below:

```html
 ...
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>  

...
```

but it still fails.

Can somebody tells me why and how could I solve this problem?

**EDITED**

The problem I facing is not about *how to return large JSON object*, but *how to post large JSON object to controller*.  I am POSTing some large JSON object (with file contents) to my controller, and at the model binding step to `MyViewModel`, exception is thrown already.

The request to the controller looks like below:

[image]

Comment: So Here also as my answer suggested you need to override the default serialization and deserialization max size, So If its related to post method then you would have to write a custom model binder that hits when your create method receives some data, In this model binder you can write your logic to deserialize without error and then send to controller.

Answer (score 2):

> Kendo MVC Grid Create action “maxJsonLength exceed”

The data you are passing back from the controller is very large and as I see you have put settings in web config also, But this didn't work for me, What I actually did was rather than letting Kendo to convert my object into Json I converted myself (where I can specify the max length of Json) and then passed the data. here is the code.

Create a C# Extension which will convert your Object into Json.

```
public static class JsonFormatter
{        
    public static string KendoJsonResult(this IEnumerable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; //Here change the default max size to Maximum possible value, that is Int32.MaxValue
        var jsonData = serializer.Serialize(enumerable.ToDataSourceResult(request));          

        return jsonData;           
    }

}
```

Then you can just change your code to convert the data into json like this.

```
return Content(dataset.KendoJsonResult(request), "application/json");
```

But still make sure your data when serialized to Json its not too large to even overflow this maximum value. Because there is of no use to send out 1000's of rows of data when the user will not even view all of them.

Comment: Thanks. You may see my Edited part in OP

Answer (score 0):

You will face this error when you get large number of records from server side.

So you need to limit the records by paging them in your database.
You will get the current offset and page size from Kendo UI Grid and using that page offset and page size you can set pagination in database.

```
 [HttpPost]

 public ActionResult Grid_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, MyViewModel row)
 {
   try
   {
     var dataset = dbsource.Skip(request.Page * request.PageSize).Take(request.PageSize).ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     ModelState.AddModelError("ERROR", ex.Message);
   }
   return Json(dataset);
 }
```

dbsource is your entity model

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstand the problem, it is not a Read action but a Create action, I am indeed POSTing a large JSON object (row in my eg) to the controller, and at the step of ASP.NET model binding (try to map the JSON object to MyViewModel), it fails. The program does not even execute into try block.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a half day surfing in Google, I finally arrived here:

[Magic Solution](http://kaushikghosh12.blogspot.hk/2014/11/aspnet-mvc-4-json-post-max-limit-problem.html)

I still do not know why it works (and why default Model Binder of ASP.NET MVC5 not work), but after using this JQuery extension, and call as the blog demostrated, the JSON Object is bound to Controller parameter successfully.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am glad the solution that i posted on my blog has worked for you.